# Why is my numpy array 2d when there's only 1d?

Tags: arrays, dataframe

I'm learning how to do multiple regression. The functions I'm using to predict return results as an array. When I go to append the data to my pandas data frame it appends, but when I try to use the data I get an error:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

So I go to check the array and see that it has 2 dimensions. I have no clue what to do, I've printed it out and it looks like it has 1 dimension to me. This is what the array looks like when printed:

```
array([[1217964.        ],
       [1215076.        ],
       [1205507.        ],
       [1200445.        ],
       [1175359.        ],
       [1172445.56110176]])
```

I thought about trying to drop a dimension, but I wouldn't know what to drop since I only see one dimension. Any help is much appreciated, thanks for helping a beginner out.

Comment: If your "result" shape is (n,1), then you can convert it to 1d (n,) by saying "result.squeeze".

Answer (score 0):

It occured to me that my array may have had an empty dimension. It seems like an oversight on the package dev for the regression functions to create 2d arrays from single dimension results, but I don't know that much.

I used the method squeeze to drop my empty dimension and now it works!